# H2 Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am using H2 database of spring boot application. I have created one account service class which is used to persist data of account, account_type and customer. Please find the code below:

Default constructor,Getter Setter,Constructor using all Fields,toString,hashCode,equals are present in each of the below class.

A Account POJO serving as an Entity as well as a Data Transfer Object i.e DTO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="account_type_id")
    private AccountType accountType;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_created", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double originalCreditAmount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double balanceAmount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean fullyPaid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int term;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private float rateOfInterest;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean escrowAttached;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean pmiAttached;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    Customer customer;
}
```

A AcountType POJO serving as an Entity as well as a Data Transfer Object i.e DTO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AccountType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String accountTypeName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String accountTypeDescription;

}
```

A Customer POJO serving as an Entity as well as a Data Transfer Object i.e DTO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String socialSecurityNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dob", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double totalLoanAmount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int bonusPoints;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "customer_since", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Date memberSince;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Education> education = new HashSet<Education>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Employment> employment = new HashSet<Employment>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Investment> investments = new HashSet<Investment>();


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Liability> liabilities = new HashSet<Liability>();


    @Column()
    private int rating;
}
```

when I am trying to make POST call to create customer , account and account type as below :

```
{
"customer": {
"id": 1,
"firstName": "Jordaya",
"lastName": "Scott",
"dateOfBirth": "1980-04-12",
"totalLoanAmount": 287000,
"bonusPoints": 70000,
"memberSince": "2000-04-11",
"socialSecurityNumber": "449-84-4944",
"rating": 7
},
"accountType": {
"id": 2,
"accountTypeName": "Savings A/C",
"accountTypeDescription": "Savings Account"
},
"dateCreated": "2017-01-01",
"originalCreditAmount": 300000,
"balanceAmount": 200000,
"fullyPaid": false,
"term": 30,
"rateOfInterest": 3.25,
"escrowAttached": false,
"pmiAttached": false
}
```

It's failing with below error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKGW84MGPACW9HTDXCS2J1P7U6J: PUBLIC.ACCOUNT FOREIGN KEY(ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ACCOUNT_TYPE(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:
insert into account (account_type_id, balance_amount, customer_id, date_created, escrow_attached, fully_paid, original_credit_amount, pmi_attached, rate_of_interest, term, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Please correct my understanding of the error. I think this error is coming because Customer and ACcount Type record are not created in DB and hence when Account is getting inserted in DB, it's unable to find account type id and hence this error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the entities with matching IDs are not present you will get integrity constraint violation.

If you want to achieve cascade creation of related entities you should add `cascade` to your relational mappings. For instance:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL...)
```

But even then when you send JSON data with specific IDs and they don't exist in DB you will get this error.

Comment: I added cascade = CascadeType.ALL to both the Join Columns (Account Type and Customer) in Account class and tried POST request again but it failed with error "detached entity passed to persist: com.microservice.model.AccountType;"

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong without the code that is doing the persisting but it looks like you are trying to save-cascade account type with ID being already set to specific value. You need to leave it null. But then the question is if this is what you want. If Account type with this id exists in DB you need to retrieve it first.